# How to add graphviz library in linux?

Tags: c, graphviz, dot

I am trying to create a graph using dot. However, it seems to not recognize attributes like fixed size. Hence, I am trying to add the graphviz library, but I do not know how to use the .deb file and use private libraries in C. here is my code, where the fixedsize attributes is not working. I want the text in the nodes to be adjusted and the node size to be the same.

```
digraph test
{
    rankdir = LR;
    "Activity" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "onCreate()" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "Activity" -> "onCreate()"
    "onCreate()" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "onStart()" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "onCreate()" -> "onStart()"
    "onStart()" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "onResume()" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "onStart()" -> "onResume()"
    "Activity" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "Activity Running" [shape=circle;fixedsize="true";width=.5;height=.5;fontsize=5];
    "Activity" -> "Activity Running"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the [`fixedsize`](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dfixedsize) attribute works:

> If **false**, the size of a node is determined by smallest width and height needed to contain its label.
>
> If **true**, the node size is specified by the values of the width and height attributes only and is not expanded to contain the text label. There will be a **warning** if the label (with margin) cannot fit within these limits.
>
> If the fixedsize attribute is set to **shape**, the width and height attributes also determine the size of the node shape, but the label can be much larger. [...] **No warning** is given if the label is too large.

The text size will never be adjusted to fit within the node, only warnings can be emitted (by using `fixedsize=true`) if the text doesn't fit the shape size.

You may parse the warnings and reduce the font size of the concerned nodes until there are no warnings left.

Answer (score 0):

For using library, you need install development package.Developmet packages in `APT system`, naming such as yourpackage-dev , for your answer, `Debian repository` has: `graphviz-dev` 
package.
But When you compile with extra library:

Every plibrary has a soname such as `pthread`, Please condider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

main()
{
     pthread_t thread1, thread2;
     const char *message1 = "Thread 1";
     const char *message2 = "Thread 2";
     int  iret1, iret2;

    /* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */

     iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
     iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);

     /* Wait till threads are complete before main continues. Unless we  */
     /* wait we run the risk of executing an exit which will terminate   */
     /* the process and all threads before the threads have completed.   */

     pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
     pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

     printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
     printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);
     exit(0);
}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
     char *message;
     message = (char *) ptr;
     printf("%s \n", message);
}
```

Compile code :

```
mohsen@debian:~$ gcc pthread.c 
/tmp/cchaTHSA.o: In function `main':
pthread.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread.c:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
pthread.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You see i got error from linker because it need  i introduce it `pthread`  library such as:

```
mohsen@debian:~$ gcc -lpthread pthread.c 
mohsen@debian:~$ ./a.out 
Thread 1 
Thread 2 
Thread 1 returns: 0
Thread 2 returns: 0
mohsen@debian:~$
```

`-lLIBRARY_NAME` introduve to gcc a library.

Comment: do I extract anything from the .deb file?

Comment: `dpkg -x your_debfile.deb TARGET_DIRECTORY`  the given command, extarct your deb in your target directory.